# Logic gate with certain truth table needed

Tags: digital-logic, multisim, boolean-algebra

I'm making a thing in Multisim and for it to work I need a logic element which works like in this truth table:

```
A B   X
0 0   A
0 1   0
1 0   A
1 1   0
```

So, if B is 0, it passes A through. And if B is 1, it outputs a zero.

Comment: Do you know of something called multiplexer ?

Comment: Yes, although the answer turned out to be way more simple

Comment: Well..the if then else caught my eyes first...

Answer (score 2):

Erm, that's just \$A \bar B\$.

Comment: You're right... Shows how much I know about gates, haha!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single-chip / gate solution, then you're looking at a 2-input MUX with one input tied to ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwrw8Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>